# Android GridView with different row number

Tags: java, android, gridview

I need to use a gridview and I want to change row numbers dynamically.

Example:

I need something like this:

[image]

I receive an ArrayList with the result, I need to show first ten results on single row and results from eleven to end on two rows layout.

is it possible to do?

Comment: i would recommend you to use GridLayout instead of GridView !!

Comment: you are confusing rows with columns

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this , you can use listview with custom adapter, you need to create 2 custom listview item with one column, and second one with 2 column.

then use

`getViewTypeCount()`

which will return 2 in your case.

and in `getView()` check the type with

`getItemViewType(int position)`

and create the appropriate view and return it.

You can check [this link](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different grid view one(with single row) for first 10 item and second(with two row) for eleven to end items.

Comment: I try to use a listview and a gridview but the result isn't very nice... because I want to scroll to search over all the records.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two layouts, both being `GridView`, one with one column and the other with two columns. I would suggest using a `ListView` for the first as it is only one column but you cannot put an unscrollable `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. I see you said you've tried this but it doesn't look very nice as they scroll separately.

Try adding a `ScrollView` around both `GridView`s and then disable the scrollability of the items inside and then it should scroll as one item.

Here is the code for the ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

and then obviously end it at the end of your XML with this:

```
</ScrollView>
```

After doing that, you should then disable the scrollability of both the `GridView`s using this line:

```
gridView.setScrollContainer(false);
```

I hope this helps! Ask if you need anything.

Comment: I try to use scrollView but the problem is that scrollView is not taking match_parent value for height. [See this pic](http://subefotos.com/ver/?bf94cdbf262ef35cf46f2924ab8e6f22o.jpg)

Comment: It appears that the `ScrollView` is but the data isn't mapping the whole screen? If not, can you add borders around the items to show me their whereabouts?

Comment: [pic with borders](http://subefotos.com/ver/?e936f32e0ed7bcb0e7d1dd10fc3e26ddo.jpg) Green color is the original layout, margins are set to match_parent. Red color is scrollView background margins are set to match_parent. And blue color is scrolview linear layout background, margins are set to match_parent

Comment: It seems the `ScrollView` fills the screen so what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is my layout code.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Listado" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvDestacadas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/celda" >
        </ListView>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gvGeneral"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dip"
            tools:listitem="@layout/celda_grid" >
        </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it always needs to be done this way i.e always first 10 will be in a single row then 
you can do it with custom adapter. Override getView, you get position as arguement return the view as required.